# Cleanup script for recordings on my Enigma2 box

Tags: bash, ksh

I've created a script to autoclean the recordings on my ET9000 Sat-Receiver, which is run by CRON.

I'm already running a script to cleanup file's older X-Days in my recordings... But I recognized that

```
find /media/hdd/Serien/my_fav_series/ -mtime +5
```

is not as efficient enough, some of the four to six file's one recording generates have a different age... And I want to asure that I'll have always a few recordings left, even if those are older than X days!

So here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1
TS=$2
REC=$((TS * 6))
RECS=$((TS + 1))
FILES=$(ls /media/hdd/Serien/$DIR/|egrep '\.ts$'|wc -l)
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

if [ $FILES -gt $TS ];
then

ls -ct /media/hdd/Serien/$DIR/|egrep '\.ts$'|tail -n+$TS > /tmp/del.lst

cd /media/hdd/Serien/$DIR

#cat /tmp/del.lst|xargs -0 rm
while IFS= read -r file
do
rm -- "$file"
done < /tmp/del.lst

cd -
rm /tmp/del.lst

echo "$DATE - $DIR - Saved the $RECS newest records & deleted older records in folder" >> /media/hdd/backup/cleanup.log
else
echo "$DATE - $DIR - Less then $TS records in folder" >> /media/hdd/backup/cleanup.log
fi
```

It work's as expected, and delete's oldest *.TS files, while keeping an amount given via parameter...

But it is not yet as intelligent as I want it to be! What I still need is an addition that delete's all the leftover's. By leftover's I mean the other not that space consuming part's of the records:

```
20121221 1628 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts
20121221 1628 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
20121221 1628 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
20121221 1628 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
```

After this will be cleaned I'll have the *.AP, *.CUTS, *.SC and maybe a *.META left in the dir. And I don't know how to write a function that will delete all file's that don't have a corresponding *.TS with em...

EDIT:

```
ls -ct /media/hdd/Serien/How_I_met_your_mother/

20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.meta
20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts
20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit

20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit
20130102 1114 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit
```

The first six line's of  the "ls -ct" output show a complete not yet cleaned recording. The second set only showing 5 files is the leftovers from an already deleted record.

What I need is a function that recognise's that first date & time pattern and sort's those in a group and then check's if that group contains a *.TS file and if it doesn't delete's the rest of the group.

I hope you can help.

Greetz
Mirco

Comment: saw that, but don't know what it means... Maybe that I never accepted old answer's? let me check that!

Comment: Found the way to accept an answer, been here seldomly excuse me! I now know it's the art of paying respect to my supporter's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, I have another idea.

1. Dump all file name into a text file (file A) using the format that you have there eg.

   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.meta
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit

   20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
   20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
   20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
   20130102 1141 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit
   20130102 1114 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit
2. Grep all file name that only ends in .ts and write to another text file (file B) eg.

   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts
3. File B only contains good recording identifier. With this identifier, remove all file that have the name from file A, don't care what is the ending. (use grep -v maybe)
   eg.

   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.meta
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.ap
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.cuts
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.ts.sc
   20130102 1600 - ProSieben HD - How I Met Your Mother.eit
4. After removing all file name related to the good identifier, you left with "junk" file name in file A
5. Delete all the file which name left in file A

Answer (score -1):

If the leftover is like what you mentioned, you need to change

```
egrep '\.ts$'
```

to

```
egrep '\.ts.*$'
```

See:

```
sharuzzaman.raslan@NL-4168 ~/test1
$ ls -1
a.ts
a.ts.ap
a.ts.cuts
a.ts.sc

sharuzzaman.raslan@NL-4168 ~/test1
$ ls -1| egrep '\.ts$'
a.ts

sharuzzaman.raslan@NL-4168 ~/test1
$ ls -1| egrep '\.ts.*$'
a.ts
a.ts.ap
a.ts.cuts
a.ts.sc
```

Comment: Thx, but grep param's are not the prob. What I want to achieve is to delete all file's that don't have a corresponding *.TS in their group. And I don't see a way to do that with a plain "ls somepath|grep somestring" run!